# Find the year with the most number of people alive in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a list of people with their birth and end years (all between `1900` and `2000`), find the year with the most number of people alive.

Here is my somewhat brute-force solution:

```
def most_populated(population, single=True):
    years = dict()
    for person in population:
        for year in xrange(person[0], person[1]):
            if year in years:
                years[year] += 1
            else:
                years[year] = 0
    return max(years, key=years.get) if single else \
           [key for key, val in years.iteritems() if val == max(years.values())]

print most_populated([(1920, 1939), (1911, 1944),
                      (1920, 1955), (1938, 1939)])
print most_populated([(1920, 1939), (1911, 1944),
                      (1920, 1955), (1938, 1939), (1937, 1940)], False)
```

I'm trying to find a more efficient way to solve this problem in `Python`. Both - `readability` and `efficiency` counts. Moreover, for some reason my code won't print `[1938, 1939]` while it should.

**Update**

Input is a `list` of tuples, where first element of a tuple is a `year` when person was born, and second element of a `tuple` is the year of death.

**Update 2**

End year (2nd part of tuple) counts as well as a year of the person being alive (so If the person dies in `Sept 1939` (we don't care about the month), he is actually alive in 1939, at least part of it). That should fix the 1939' missing in results.

**Best solution?**

While readability counts in favor of [@joran-beasley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31522489/1554153), for bigger input most efficient algorithm was provided by [@njzk2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31523813/1554153). Thanks @hannes-ovrén for providing analysis in [IPython notebook on Gist](https://gist.github.com/hovren/bf5335ba45cd7eee811e)

Comment: `years[year] = 1` for starters

Comment: @njzk2 Technically I think you're right from a readability standpoint, but every years[n] will be initialized to 0 and will still yield the "most_populated" year correctly. If the count was bring returned, I'd agree with you but only the year is being returned.

Comment: Let's say that you have 10 people born in 2000 and they all die in 2080.  Then there are another 10 who are born in 2080 and they die in 2160.  Do you want the maximum people alive to be 10 or 20 or 15 or something else?  What is your assumption about what's going on in 2080?

Comment: Your approach—modelling individual timelines—will work, but there's a more efficient algorithm using *dynamic programming*. **Hint**: people alive at start of year Y = total people born before year Y - total people died before year Y. Note that the combinations of (birth, death) don't matter, only the dates.

Comment: For a harder problem playing with some of the same ideas, see Google Code Jam's The Great Wall https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/2437488/dashboard#s=p2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> def most_pop(pop):
...     pop_flat = chain.from_iterable(range(i,j+1) for i,j in pop)
...     return Counter(pop_flat).most_common()
...
>>> most_pop([(1920, 1939), (1911, 1944), (1920, 1955), (1938, 1939)])[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, looks very neat. How can I change the code to count the 2nd part of tuple as well ? (death year should also count)

Comment: `xrange(i,j+1) for i,j in pop` in python2 and `range(i,j+1) for i,j in pop` is better!

Comment: Accepted due to best timeit test: https://gist.github.com/oskar-j/308aafbb7ae44df7fed1 , result: joran-beasley: 0.0668609038671

Comment: I like that answer because it is short, clear and readable, but beware of the complexity, if you have a more significant number of people or years to handle.

Comment: @oski86, Love the benchmark. It would be interesting to see results for different sizes of the input list as well. I would guess that my numpy version suffers for small N due to the construction of the `people_alive` array. For the record, I do think this answer should be the accepted one. I like it :)

Comment: Actually, I take that back. This algorithm is by far the *slowest* of the ones tried so far. It just happens to be fast for really small population sizes. For larger populations *njzk2_var2* is fastest. See benchmark plot here: https://gist.github.com/hovren/bf5335ba45cd7eee811e the *hannes_v2* algorithm is exactly the same as my old one, but without the namedtuple, since that added a bit of overhead.

Comment: That's what I wanted to try yesterday (provide bigger rand test data), but it where already wee hours. I'm not sure about changing the accepted answer, but I have one idea, I'll update content in the question with providing a winning solution separately for a small and big data on input.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution I just though of:

- Create 2 tables, `birthdates` and `deathdates`.
- Accumulate birth dates and death dates in those tables.
- Browse those tables to accumulate the number of alive people at the time.

Grand total complexity is `O(n)`

### Implementation

```
from collections import Counter

def most_populated(population, single=True):
    birth = map(lambda x: x[0], population)
    death = map(lambda x: x[1] + 1, population)
    b = Counter(birth)
    d = Counter(death)
    alive = 0
    years = {}
    for year in range(min(birth), max(death) + 1):
        alive = alive + b[year] - d[year]
        years[year] = alive
    return max(years, key=years.get) if single else \
           [key for key, val in years.iteritems() if val == max(years.values())]
```

### Better

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import accumulate
import operator

def most_populated(population, single=True):
    delta = Counter(x[0] for x in population)
    delta.subtract(Counter(x[1]+1 for x in population))
    start, end = min(delta.keys()), max(delta.keys())
    years = list(accumulate(delta[year] for year in range(start, end)))
    return max(enumerate(years), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0] + start if single else \
           [i + start for i, val in enumerate(years) if val == max(years)]
```

Comment: using a table instead of a Counter, we could use itertools.accumulate to compute the values for each year in a single call

Comment: Neat. This is the dynamic programming algorithm I hinted to.

Comment: so if i call it with `most_populated([(-10025, -10000), (1960, 2010)])`, for 2 people it will do >10200 iterations? This is terrible!

Answer (score 4):

I would go like this:

- Sort persons by birth year (`unborn` list)
- Starting from the first born

  - Put that person in the `alive` list
  - Using an insertion sort by date of death (the list stays sorted, so use a binary search)
  - Until you reach a person that was not born that year
- Then, starting from the person in the `alive` list that dies first, remove it from the list.
- Put the size of the `alive` list in a dict
- Increment the year
- Loop until the `unborn` and `alive` lists are empty

Complexity should be around `O((m + n) * log(m))` (each year is considered only once, and each person only twice, multiplied by the insertion cost in the `alive` list)

### Implementation

```
from bisect import insort

def most_populated(population, single=True):
    years = dict()
    unborn = sorted(population, key=lambda x: -x[0])
    alive = []
    dead = []
    for year in range(unborn[-1][0], max(population, key=lambda x: x[1])[1] + 1):
        while unborn and unborn[-1][0] == year:
            insort(alive, -unborn.pop()[1])
        while alive and alive[-1] == -(year - 1):
            dead.append(-alive.pop())
        years[year] = len(alive)
    return max(years, key=years.get) if single else \
           [key for key, val in years.iteritems() if val == max(years.values())]
```

Comment: This will be very slow for large populations because of `insort`.

Comment: @DSM: insort is `O(n)`, which makes my initial complexity computation wrong, but nontheless this is equivalent in complexity to considering each year of each person.

Comment: @nkjz2: I think I'd treat the input data as an event queue, with births being (t, 1) and deaths being (t, -1).  You can sort that in N log N, and then simply loop over each event either adding or decreasing to the total population, tracking whatever you want.

Comment: @DSM: yep, I realized something like that can be done. Also, since it is a relatively known set of dates, you can use a bucket sort (`O(n)`), or a Counter, like what I started in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use numpy slicing, which is quite neat, and should also be quite efficient:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import namedtuple

Person = namedtuple('Person', ('birth', 'death'))
people = [Person(1900,2000), Person(1950,1960), Person(1955, 1959)]

START_YEAR = 1900
END_YEAR = 2000
people_alive = np.zeros(END_YEAR - START_YEAR + 1) # Alive each year

for p in people:
    a = p.birth - START_YEAR
    b = p.death - START_YEAR + 1 # include year of death
    people_alive[a:b] += 1

# Find indexes of maximum aliveness and convert to year
most_alive = np.flatnonzero(people_alive == people_alive.max()) + START_YEAR
```

**EDIT** It seems like the namedtuple adds a bit of overhead, so to speed up a bit more, remove the namedtuple and do
`for birth, death in people:` instead.

Comment: you really think `people_alive[a:b] += 1` is `O(1)`?

Comment: That is incredibly true. Not sure what I was thinking. :)

Comment: Timeit 10000 times seems to return a constant execution time, probably with bigger test data on the input it may work quite fine, but it needs further tests. +1 for using the numpy

Comment: Considering that the maximum length of the range `a:b` is (assuming normal humans) in the order of 100, you could consider it to be O(1).

Answer (score 1):

1. Just put the birth and death years into a dict. If it is birth, increase the value by 1. or vice versa.
2. Sort the dict by keys and iterate by reading the current number of the alive people.
3. Follow the 'maxAlive' an 'theYear' to get the first year with the highest number

   ```
   years = {} 

   for p in people:
       if p.birth in years:
           years[p.birth] += 1
       else:
           years[p.birth] = 1

       if p.death in years:
           years[p.death] -= 1
       else:
           years[p.death] = -1

   alive = 0
   maxAlive = 0
   theYear = people[0].birth
   for year in sorted(years):
       alive += years[year]
       if alive > maxAlive:
           maxAlive = alive
           theYear = year
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Without importing anything, and using a class for readability, here's my solution. Let me know what you think! I also made a separate function for getMaxBirthYear in case you're at an interview and someone wants you to code that out rather than using built in functions (I used them :) )

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, birth=None, death=None):
    self.birth=birth
    self.death=death

def getPopulationPeak(people):
  maxBirthYear = getMaxBirthYear(people)
  deltas = getDeltas(people, maxBirthYear)
  currentSum = 0 
  maxSum = 0
  maxYear = 0
  for year in sorted(deltas.keys()):
    currentSum += deltas[year]
    if currentSum > maxSum:
      maxSum = currentSum
      maxYear = year
  return maxYear, maxSum

def getMaxBirthYear(people):
  return max(people, key=lambda x: x.birth).birth

def getDeltas(people, maxBirthYear):
  deltas = dict()
  for person in people:
    if person.birth in deltas.keys():
      deltas[person.birth] += 1
    else:
      deltas[person.birth] = 1
    if person.death + 1 in deltas.keys():
      deltas[person.death + 1] -= 1
    elif person.death + 1 not in deltas.keys() and person.death <= maxBirthYear: # We can skip deaths after the last birth year
      deltas[person.death + 1] = -1
  return deltas

testPeople = [
  Person(1750,1802),
  Person(2000,2010),
  Person(1645,1760),
  Person(1985,2002),
  Person(2000,2050),
  Person(2005,2080),
]

print(getPopulationPeak(testPeople))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
def max_pop(pop):
    p = 0; max = (0,0)
    for y,i in sorted(chain.from_iterable([((b,1), (d+1,-1)) for b,d in pop])):
        p += i
        if p > max[1]: max=(y,p)
    return max
```

It's not affected by the year span but is nlogn in the |pop| (unless you'd roll out a radix sort which would be ~ 10n for a thousand year span and should be faster for |pop|>1000 ). Can't have both. A very general solution would have to scan first and decide which algo to use based on measured year span and |pop|.

Answer (score 0):

my answer

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class AlogrimVarsta {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int startYear = 1890;
        int stopYear = 2000;

        List<Person> listPerson = new LinkedList<>();

        listPerson.add(new Person(1910, 1940));
        listPerson.add(new Person(1920, 1935));
        listPerson.add(new Person(1900, 1950));
        listPerson.add(new Person(1890, 1920));
        listPerson.add(new Person(1890, 2000));
        listPerson.add(new Person(1945, 2000));

        Map<Integer, Integer> mapPersoaneCareAuTrait = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (int x = startYear; x <= stopYear; x++) {
            mapPersoaneCareAuTrait.put(x, 0);
        }

        for (int x = startYear; x <= stopYear; x++) {
            for (Person per : listPerson) {

                int value = mapPersoaneCareAuTrait.get(x);

                if (per.getBorn() == x) {
                    mapPersoaneCareAuTrait.put(x, value + 1);
                    continue;
                }

                if (per.getDie() == x) {
                    mapPersoaneCareAuTrait.put(x, value + 1);
                    continue;
                }

                if ((per.getDie() - per.getBorn() > per.getDie() - x) && (per.getDie() - x > 0)) {
                    mapPersoaneCareAuTrait.put(x, value + 1);
                    continue;
                }

            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> mapEntry : mapPersoaneCareAuTrait.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("an " + mapEntry.getKey() + " numar " + mapEntry.getValue());            
        }

    }

    static class Person {
        final private int born;
        final private int die;

        public Person(int pBorn, int pDie) {
            die = pDie;
            born = pBorn;
        }

        public int getBorn() {
            return born;
        }

        public int getDie() {
            return die;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a Java answer, the OP asked for Python solutions. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I don't get the use of the second if statement, why are you adding +1 to the year of death? The first if statement is clear though.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [(1920, 1939), (1911, 1944),(1920, 1955), (1938, 1939)]
union = set({})
for i in l:
    temp = set(range(min(i), max(i) + 1))
    if len(union) == 0:
        union = temp
    union = temp & union
print(union)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer]. This is particularly important when answering old questions (this one is over six years old) with existing answers.

Answer (score -2):

I came over the following code that is exactly what you need.

Let's say the range of years is 1900 - 2000

### Steps of the algorithm

1. Construct an array X of 100 integers (all initialized to zero; 101 integers if the year 2000 is included).
2. For each of the N people, increment X[birth year - 1900] by one and decrement X[death year - 1900] by one.
3. Iterate through X, maintaining a sum of each element as you go. The year with the most people alive is 1900 plus the index where the sum is maximum.

### Code (Python as requested)

```
def year_with_max_population(people):
population_changes = [0 for _ in xrange(1900, 2000)]
for person in people:
    population_changes[person.birth_year - 1900] += 1
    population_changes[person.death_year - 1900] -= 1
max_population = 0
max_population_index = 0
population = 0
for index, population_change in enumerate(population_changes):
    population += population_change
    if population > max_population:
        max_population = population
        max_population_index = index
return 1900 + max_population_index
```

credit 'Brian Schmitz'  [here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-someone-find-the-year-with-the-most-people-alive)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).