# Find the year with the most number of people alive in PHP

Tags: php, date, oop

Given a list of people with their birth and end years (all between 1900 and 2017), find the year with the most number of people alive.

```
<?php
class Person {
    function __construct($birth, $death) {
    $this->birthYear = $birth;
    $this->deathYear = $death;
  }
};

$people = [
  new Person(1925, 1972),//47
  new Person(1901, 1960),//59
  new Person(1942, 1999),//57
  new Person(1960, 2010),//50
  new Person(1931, 2017),//86
  new Person(1961, 1995),//34
  new Person(1919, 1982),//63
];
$birth = array_column($people,"birthYear");
$death = array_column($people,"deathYear");
$START_YEAR = 1900;
$END_YEAR = 2017+1;
$people_alive = [];
$people = json_decode(json_encode($people),true);

foreach($people as $k=>$v){
    $a = $v['birthYear'] - $START_YEAR;
    $b = $v['deathYear'] - $START_YEAR +1;
    $people_alive[]= $b-$a +1;
}
print_r($people_alive);
```

I tried to convert solution from [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31522450/find-the-year-with-the-most-number-of-people-alive-in-python) to PHP but this is not what I want.
Solution from python

```
Array
(
    [0] => 49
    [1] => 61
    [2] => 59
    [3] => 52
    [4] => 88
    [5] => 36
    [6] => 65
)
```

I want a year in which most number of people were alive.
I am confused about how this logic will going to be created.

Comment: Check out `array_multisort` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php#example-6190

Comment: @Kyle Thank you for your suggestion but still I didn't get how that will going to help me

Comment: maybe it won't. I think I misunderstood the question. My bad.

Comment: "I want a year in which ... "  If there are 10 years where the maximum number of people were alive, do you care _which_ year is returned?

Comment: Nope, I don't care. If I can get list like 1925=>25,1950=>21 etc., I will figure out in which year most number of people were alive

Comment: In that case, the answer that was given but deleted actually seemed to do that. I don't know if it was the most efficient, but I will give the author of that answer a chance to re-post it.

Comment: @PatrickQ That would be great!  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution will be to go through all the years and count how many people alive there are on a given year. Then, find the year with the max number - that will be the year with the most number of people alive. Keep in mind that this solution is not optimal and have total complexity `O(n)`:

```
<?php
class Person {
    public function __construct($birth, $death) {
        $this->birthYear = $birth;
        $this->deathYear = $death;
    }
};

$people = [
    new Person(1925, 1972),//47
    new Person(1901, 1960),//59
    new Person(1942, 1999),//57
    new Person(1960, 2010),//50
    new Person(1931, 2017),//86
    new Person(1961, 1995),//34
    new Person(1919, 1982),//63
];

$start = 1900;
$end = 2017;

// create list of years in given time frame
$years = array_fill($start, $end - $start + 1, 0);

// iterate through all the people
foreach ($people as $person) {
    for ($i = $person->birthYear; $i <= $person->deathYear; ++$i) {
        $years[$i] += 1;
    }
}

// the maximum number of people alive in one year
$max_count = max($years);
// the year with the most number of people alive
$max_year = array_search($max_count, $years);
```

Comment: I think your answer will going to work. I am checking.

Comment: Great! Thanks @krlv. This is what I wanted