# How many presidents have been alive at any time?

Tags: r

This is a simplified example of the problem I'm having with my actual dataset. I'd like to know how many presidents (current, future, and past) have been alive in any year going back to 1776. I have a dataset showing the birth year and death year (or NA) for every president. Here's the code.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(rvest)

site <- read_html("https://www.presidentsusa.net/birth.html")

site %>% 
  html_table() %>% 
  .[[1]] %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  select(birthdate = `Birth Date`, deathdate = `Death Date`) %>% 
  mutate(birthdate = year(mdy(birthdate)), deathdate = year(mdy(deathdate)))
```

In case the site changes and breaks my code, here's the `dput` of my dataset.

```
structure(list(birthdate = c(1732, 1735, 1743, 1751, 1758, 1767, 
1767, 1782, 1773, 1790, 1795, 1784, 1800, 1804, 1791, 1809, 1808, 
1822, 1822, 1831, 1829, 1837, 1833, 1843, 1858, 1857, 1856, 1865, 
1872, 1874, 1882, 1884, 1890, 1917, 1908, 1913, 1913, 1924, 1911, 
1924, 1946, 1946, 1961, 1946), deathdate = c(1799, 1826, 1826, 
1836, 1831, 1848, 1845, 1862, 1841, 1862, 1849, 1850, 1874, 1869, 
1868, 1865, 1875, 1885, 1893, 1881, 1886, 1908, 1901, 1901, 1919, 
1930, 1924, 1923, 1933, 1964, 1945, 1972, 1969, 1963, 1973, 1994, 
2006, NA, 2004, 2018, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -44L))
```

I'd like to create a two-column tibble with one column for the year and the second column showing how many presidents were alive for the entire year (excluding anybody who died during the year). Here's the first few rows of my desired output.

```
tibble(year = 1776:1779, alive = c(8,8,8,7))
```

I'd appreciate any guidance here. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31522450/find-the-year-with-the-most-number-of-people-alive-in-python) is a similar question in Python but I'm having trouble adapting it to R. Here's what I've tried so far. It works but it seems like there should be a more efficient way that doesn't involve running two `filter()` operations on the entire dataset for every single year.

```
filter <- dplyr::filter
df <- mutate(df, deathdate = replace_na(deathdate, 9999))

count_living <- function(year) {
  df %>%
    filter(birthdate < year, deathdate >= year) %>%
    nrow()
}

tibble(year = 1776:2020,
       alive = map_int(1776:2020, count_living))
```

Comment: What does `NA` suggest? They are alive?

Comment: @RonakShah Yes, NA means the president is still alive.

Comment: I assume the data preparation steps are more or less irrelevant for your actual question and can be removed. Rather include what you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: @IanCampbell That's odd. I'm not getting an error. Scraping can be unpredictable, so I added the dput just in case.

Comment: @Henrik Thanks for the feedback, I just added what I've tried so far.

Comment: I think this could be solved with a `data.table` non-equi join between the ranges (birth to death) and the years. Use the `by = .EACHI` feature to count the number of matches (`.N`) for _each_ year. Quite a few posts of this kind on SO. Search for "data.table non-equi join .EACHI". `setDT(df)`; `df[is.na(deathdate), deathdate := 2020]`; `df[.(yr = min(df$birthdate):2020), on = .(birthdate <= yr, deathdate >= yr), .N, by = .EACHI, allow.cartesian = TRUE]`

Answer (score 2):

You could create a sequence between `birthdate` and `deathdate` after replacing `NA` with current `year` and `count` number of times a `year` is encountered.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(deathdate = replace(deathdate, is.na(deathdate), year(Sys.Date())), 
         year = purrr::map2(birthdate, deathdate, seq)) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(year) %>%
  count(year, name = 'alive')


# A tibble: 289 x 2
#    year alive
#   <int> <int>
# 1  1732     1
# 2  1733     1
# 3  1734     1
# 4  1735     2
# 5  1736     2
# 6  1737     2
# 7  1738     2
# 8  1739     2
# 9  1740     2
#10  1741     2
# … with 279 more rows
```

---

Using the same logic in base R :

```
df$deathdate[is.na(df$deathdate)] <- as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"))
stack(table(unlist(Map(seq, df$birthdate, df$deathdate))))
```

Comment: Not sure how would that work. What do you expect with `year(date, na.rm = T)` when `date` has `NA` ?

Comment: Why do you need `na.rm = TRUE` for that? By default `year(date)` returns 2020 and `NA` for input `date <- c(as.Date("2020-12-24", format="%Y-%m-%d"), NA)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach with `IRanges`, which is highly optimized for this problem:

```
library(IRanges)
data$deathdate[is.na(data$deathdate)] <- 3000
Presidents <- IRanges(start = data$birthdate,end = data$deathdate)    
QueryYears <- IRanges(start = 1732:2020, width = 1)
Hits <- countOverlaps(QueryYears,Presidents)
Result <- data.frame(Year = 1732:2020, Count = Hits)

Result[order(Result$Count,decreasing = TRUE),]
#    Year Count
#91  1822    18
#92  1823    18
#93  1824    18
#94  1825    18
#95  1826    18
#100 1831    18
#102 1833    18
#103 1834    18
#104 1835    18
#105 1836    18
#106 1837    18
#...
```

I try not to answer questions with yet another package, but `IRanges` is a great tool to have in your R toolkit. It can improve the performance of solutions to this kind of problem by orders of magnitude.